# Cause of shoot-through in H-bridge

Tags: mosfet, h-bridge, inductive, shoot-through

I've designed an H-bridge for a 15A DC motor. Power is applied by plugging in a very high-capacity Lithium battery. Unfortunately, when I plug in the battery, one of the transistors goes pop instantly and shorts across itself. This ultimately shorts the battery to itself which makes me unhappy. V_BATT is a 14.8V Lithium battery. The transistors are [N-channel MOSFETS](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/PSMN4R0-40YS.pdf). U1 is an [H-bridge driver IC](http://cache.freescale.com/files/analog/doc/data_sheet/MC33883.pdf).

[image]

I've come up with two possible root causes. I'd like some help figuring out which one is more likely.

1. A nasty inductive spike is being generated during the initial current surge due to the natural inductance of the battery cables and copper traces. The spike exceeds the Vds of the FETs, causing them to fail. The Vds of the FETs I'm using is 40V, so I find it likely the inductive spike is exceeding that. I plan to use a snubber and voltage clamp circuit to reduce the spike.

Or,

2. The sudden rise of voltage on the drain of the FETs causes the gate voltage to also rise due to the intrinsic capacitance between the drain and the gate. This effectively turns on all of the FETs and causes shoot-through and burns them out.

I'm leaning towards #1 being the main culprit, but I can't justify why #2 isn't also causing a problem. Especially since I have 50\$\Omega\$ resistors on each gate pin. Even if the gate drive pins of U1 are trying to hold the pins low, the resistors would isolate the gate pins for a short time.

Is it likely the problem is a combination of both items? Or is #2 not really an issue? If #2 is actually happening, what can be done to suppress it?

Comment: What have you got driving your 4 phase inputs?

Comment: Directly from a uC.

Comment: Have you watched on a scope, what happens to those uc outputs when you plug in the battery?

Comment: No, but I know what you're getting at. In my first attempt to make a "quick fix" on the board, I isolated the h-bridge power from the uC/driver using separate batteries (with common grounds, of course) . I plugged in the uC/driver's battery first and then the h-bridge battery. Therefore, the uC and the driver IC were fully powered on and stable before I applied power to the h-bridge. With that in mind, I don't think it's a power-on artifact of the uC or the driver.

Comment: Try powering the mcu separately with the phase inputs in a good state then plug in the battery

Comment: I think we were typing at the same time. See my comment above.

Comment: @JohnD, I think you misread my comment above. The uC provides only input logic to an H-bridge driver chip (U1) in my schematic. The uC is not driving the FETs directly. Also, under nominal conditions I agree the high-side FET couldn't turn on. However, the problem is occurring instantly on power-on, so I suspect there's a high-voltage spike that may be the culprit. Far from nominal conditions.

Comment: Datasheet for the H-bridge driver IC (labeled U1 in your diagram)?

Comment: @JayJ, sure thing. Question has been edited with link to the datasheet.

Comment: From the H-bridge driver IC, page 10. "There is no internal circuit to prevent the external high-side 
and low-side MOSFETs from conducting at the same time." Which is a huge opportunity for failure. To test try running the motor in one direction (tie H-bridge inputs LS1 and HS2 to ground).

Comment: Agreed. But this is happening instantly on power-up of the H-bridge. Per one of my comments above, the IC was already powered up and stabilized. The inputs were all off, so there was no chance for an accidental shoot-through condition in software.

Comment: Which mosfet is dying?  Is it always the same one?  How many times has it died?

Comment: It's been the same one, but I've only tried it twice. Not enough of a dataset to draw a conclusion.

Comment: You're right, I did misinterpret your comment above, sorry.  If the problem happens on turn-on and you're SURE the gates are off (did you measure Vgs?) then I suppose you could have an overvoltage VDS avalanche, but it sounds unlikely.  FETs are pretty rugged for single pulse avalanche energy.  Do you have a large bulk capacitor right between the drains of the top FETs and sources of the bottom FETs?

Comment: If it's always the same fet, even when you replace the busted part, that implies that there's something more than just inductive kick back as that would be a little more random I'd imagine, and the output capacitance doesn't really seem large enough to couple enough charge into the gate to turn it on.

Comment: Did you happen to try adding a gate-to-source resistors to hold the MOSFETs off?  Something like a 1k directly between gate and source, especially on the high side?  That would be an attempt at addressing possibility #2 you are raising above.  As a serious debug-only test, you could short GS on all the MOSFETS (no way for them to be ON now!) and see if the same thing happens.

Comment: @DanLaks In your response to the question "Which MOSFET has been failing?" you have replied "The same one", which is not helping at all if you want us to help you. I have checked everything you wrote so far, and you have not mentioned anywhere WHICH MOSFET EXACTLY is failing, unless I have missed something.

Comment: Also, what is the zener diode model across the gate-source leads of the upper MOSFETs? What are its ratings in volts and watts?

Answer (score 1):

Some driver circuits dont have UVLO [undervoltage-lockout], and they can come on wrong or oscillate at the beginning of the work cycle. Do a transistor Schmitt-trigger undervoltage-lockout circuit with several independent outputs: one output to keep the driver disabled by applying a shut-down on its input, and other outputs to keep the gates of MOSFETs down to source voltage (careful with the upper transistors gates, they have different source potential and therefore the transistors to lockdown them should be kept on by some voltage shifters, like the voltage shifter in the H-bridge driver inside the integrated circuit...)

The trigger should release the gate lockdowns and the driver shutdown simultaneously, or eventually prioritise the lockdown of the top mosfet by the synchronous diodes lockdown (the top mosfet to not be possible to be "activated" without diodes being "activated") Am sorry but my english may be not very well inteligible here... Try use anyway a safety circuit to not release the gate of transistors (to shunt them to source) for a few miliseconds after the battery is first applied.

A possible help (yes, i suspect more the #two of your guesses) can be use of a coil on the supply wire, several tens of microhenries, plus several thousand microfarads parallel on the supply lines. This will slow the voltage rise on the supply and possible avoid Miller charging of the gates. Calculate the number of microhenries and microfarads to slowdown the rising voltage to 0,5-1V/microsecond and should be fine from this point of view.. But from my opinion, i will apply the previous method, the UVLO circuits..

Comment: The MC33883 has an undervoltage protection feature ("The VCC and VCC2 pins have undervoltage (UV) and overvoltage (OV) shutdown. If one of the supply voltage drops below the undervoltage threshold or rises above the 
overvoltage threshold, the gate outputs are switched LOW in order to switch off the external MOSFETs"), just search for "undervoltage" in the [datasheet](http://cache.freescale.com/files/analog/doc/data_sheet/MC33883.pdf), so the driver turn-on behaviour will be well behaved. I think OP was most likely misdriving the inputs of the gate driver, e.g. due to a bug in the Uc code.

Comment: True, i searched and its there, but it's at 4 Volts. This may be open for troubles.. Anyway, i still recommand an external UVLO circuit to keep all the gates down until voltage reaches 11V and to be slightly temporized (a few miliseconds) at opening the gates. And definitely to open the bottom transistor gates first.

Answer (score 1):

Use gate driver ICs. A few bucks and problem solved. That is what those are designed for, and they do it well. But if you have the luxury of design time and money to R & D this problem, good for you. I usually don't time & money to burn due to the engineering time which kills any minute savings you were making unless you selling a "million" gidgets. If don't R&D well it can fail in the field as well. Just a thought.

Answer (score -3):

I think, if you are going to use N-Channel fets for high-side and low-side, you need to develop appropriate drive voltages for the high side ones. (There are IC's that will do this for you). If you don't want to go that route, you may need to change the high-side (the ones that connect to the + rail) fets to P-Channel types and drive them accordingly. :-)

Comment: It doesn't seem like you read the question or looked at the schematic I posted. The MC33883 H-bridge drivers that are labeled in the schematic and linked to in the text provides the necessary boost capacitor drive for the high-side FETs.